# Enable or Disable Paypal Sandbox (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently running Woocommerce through Wordpress with Paypal for payments. The site is about to go live and I was wondering if the Woocommerce option "Paypal Sandbox" should be enabled or disabled if I'm finished testing.

Thank you all!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You should ask this on [wordpress.se], but I'd be concerned about setting a site live if I didn't know the answer to something as fundamental as this.

Comment: @MikeW afaik this shouldn't be asked on on the WPSE because it is a third party plugin and is off topic for site.

Comment: @Howlin Maybe so, but it's off-topic here for the same reason, so it should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Did you mean "Paypal for WooCommerce"?  That Sandbox option is only for testing.  If you're going live you want to make sure it's NOT checked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress administration

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Woocommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard/) site:

> You can enable PayPal Sandbox as a testing area **during the development
>   of your store**. With sandbox enabled no payments will be taken.

(emphases added)

If the website is going live and you are finished testing then yes turn off the sandbox or you won't get any payments for anything ordered.